# Getting OpenLayers to scale past nativeZoom like Leaflet?

Tags: openlayers, zoom

Is there any way to get OpenLayers 3 to scale past the native zoom as is possible in Leaflet?

For reference, in Leaflet simply set maxZoom higher than maxNativeZoom and it stretches or perhaps scales the tile for a closer view.

In this example tiles go to 16. I'd like to scale 16 up to 18 for a closer view:

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map_div',
    renderer: 'canvas',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([X_LO,X_LA], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 16,
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 16
        })
    });

L1=new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url:'http://blahblah.com/map_tiles.php?Z={z}&X={x}&Y={y}'
        }),
    maxResolution:152.87,// 9
    minResolution:1.94// 16
    });
map.addLayer(L1);
```

**Solution** from @erilem

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map_div',
    renderer: 'canvas',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([X_LO,X_LA], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 16,
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18
        })
    });

L1=new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url:'http://blahblah.com/map_tiles.php?Z={z}&X={x}&Y={y}',
        maxZoom: 16
        })
    });
map.addLayer(L1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to have more resolutions/zoom levels in your view than in your XYZ source.

By default the `maxZoom` for `ol.source.XYZ` is 42. You will want to set it to 16 in your case. You also want to remove `maxResolution` and `minResolution` from your layer, otherwise the layer won't be displayed when the view resolution is outside the `[minResolution, maxResolution]` range.

And you will need to set `maxZoom` to 18 in your view. So when the view will change to zoom level 17 and 18 tiles at zoom level 16 will be used.